# Sharepoint integration with my Angular JS docxtemplater webapp

Tags: angularjs, firebase, sharepoint, office365

I currently have an angular JS webapp where I generate a document using docxtemplater from my firebase cloud function. I wonder if it is possible to have the generated document automatically available on my company's sharepoint (via a link?)

Comment: "I generate a document using docxtemplater from my firebase cloud function" => Do you store it after generation? If yes, where do you store it? **OR** you stream it to the user's browser?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec many thanks. I store the document in the firebase storage and then send it as an attachment to the user's email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that after generating the docs you store them in Cloud Storage for Firebase. So it will be easy to generate a signed URL for each of these docs.

You would then need to implement a process that push/pull the signedURLs to/from Sharepoint.

From the Firebase side, Cloud Functions could help by:

- Calling an API exposed by the backend of your Sharepoint infrastructure and posting the signed URLs;
- OR, by exposing an API endpoint (HTTPS Cloud Function) that your Sharepoint infrastructure would call to get the signed URLs.

Comment: Hey @DejiJames, did you have time to consider my answer?